# Linear regression with a given covariance structure in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, covariance, gaussian-process

I want to fit a linear model in R with a given covariance structure:
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$
where the covariance matrix of $\epsilon$ is block diagonal by a grouping factor. Suppose there are $B$ blocks. Within block $b$, the covariance is of the following form:
$$\sigma_1^211^T+\sigma_2^2G_b+\sigma_3^2I$$
where $1$ is the vector of all ones, $I$ is the identity matrix and $G_b$ is generated by a Gaussian process kernel: $G_{b}(i,j)=k(x_{bi},x_{bj},\theta)$. Here $x_{bi}$ and $x_{bj}$ are sample $i,j$ in block $b$. $\theta$ is an unknown parameter of the kernel $k$. $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3,\theta$ are all unknown and are the same across all blocks. An example of $k$ is 
$$k(x_{bi},x_{bj},\theta)=\exp(-\frac{||x_{bi}-x_{bj}||^2}{\theta^2})$$

Is there any existing packages in R to fit the above model and implement inference?

Comment: It is easy to fit this model in SAS by PROC MIXED.

Answer (score 2):

You could fit this type of model using the `lme()` function from the [**nlme**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nlme) package; a generic example is:

```
lme(y ~ x1 + x2 + ..., data = <your_data>, random = ~ 1 | block_id, 
    correlation = corGaus(form = ~ x1 | block_id))
```

The only difference from your postulated covariance matrix will be that in the above code you have $\sigma^2 = \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2$.